# Confusing step in WolframAlpha integration

Tags: calculus, integration

The problem was: ∫2e^(-x/4)dx

And the steps WolframAlpha used were:

1.) Take the integral ∫2e^(-x/4)dx

2.) Factor out constants 2∫e^(-x/4)dx

3.) For the integrand e^(-x/4), substitute u = (-x/4) and du = -1/4 dx : -8∫e^(u)du

The rest I understand, but where does the -1/4 dx come from?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

$F(x) = \int_a^{u(x)} f(t) dt\\
F'(x) = f(u(x)) u'(x)$

Operating in reverse.

If you want to integrate some function that has the right "shape."

$\int f(u(x)) u'(x) dx$

i.e $\int e^{-\frac {x}{4}}(-\frac 14 dx)$
then you can say $u(x) = -\frac {x}{4}, u'(x) = -\frac {1}{4}$

although we usually write it as $du = -\frac 14 dx$

$\int e^{u} du = e^u + C$
and then reverse the substitution.

$e^{-\frac x4} + C$

But sometimes you get something that is not so perfect.

$\int e^{-\frac {x}{4}} dx$

then you do a little trickery to get the right form

$\int e^{-\frac {x}{4}}(-4)(-\frac 14) dx\\
-4\int e^{-\frac {x}{4}}(-\frac 14 dx)\\$

and substitute.

Answer (score 0):

Because the derivative of $u$ is $-\frac{1}{4}$, think of it as $\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)x$; the derivative is going to be the constant.